# Change BreadCrumb component that was done with react-router v5 to react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, breadcrumbs, custom-component

I want to change this BreadCrumb component that was done with react-router v5 to react router v6.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Breadcrumbs as MUIBreadcrumbs,
  Link,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Breadcrumbs = props => {
  const {
    history,
    location: { pathname }
  } = props;
  const pathnames = pathname.split("/").filter(x => x);
  return (
    <MUIBreadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
      {pathnames.length > 0 ? (
        <Link onClick={() => history.push("/")}>Home</Link>
      ) : (
        <Typography> Home </Typography>
      )}
      {pathnames.map((name, index) => {
        const routeTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join("/")}`;
        const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
        return isLast ? (
          <Typography key={name}>{name}</Typography>
        ) : (
          <Link key={name} onClick={() => history.push(routeTo)}>
            {name}
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </MUIBreadcrumbs>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Breadcrumbs);
```

I try looking out information about how to use the `withRouter` now it seems that we can use hooks, `useLocation` and `useHistory`, as I'm new to React I don't know how to implement those, the code above is in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ellis-4d0lc?file=/src/App.js:122-128).

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your attempt at the conversion, including any issues you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding just this `Breadcrumbs` component, since it is a function component you can use the React hooks. The v5 `useHistory` hook was replaced by the `useNavigate` hook that returns a `navigate` function instead of a `history` object. `useLocation` hook returns the same `location` object.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Breadcrumbs as MUIBreadcrumbs,
  Link,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Breadcrumbs = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const pathnames = pathname.split("/").filter(Boolean);

  return (
    <MUIBreadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
      {pathnames.length ? (
        <Link onClick={() => navigate("/")}>Home</Link>
      ) : (
        <Typography> Home </Typography>
      )}
      {pathnames.map((name, index) => {
        const routeTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join("/")}`;
        const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
        return isLast ? (
          <Typography key={name}>{name}</Typography>
        ) : (
          <Link key={name} onClick={() => navigate(routeTo)}>
            {name}
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </MUIBreadcrumbs>
  );
};

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

You'll OFC need to follow the [upgrade from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) to upgrade the rest of your app to use the v6 component APIs so routing and navigation and accessing the old "route props" works.

Comment: I have a follow-up question with this component, let's say if I'm navigating between windows with forms and I don't want to lose data that was entered but not submitted, what can I implement in this component?

Comment: @FernadoCastellon You very likely will need to persist this form data/state higher in the app's ReactTree such that the component it's located in remains mounted while navigating between routes. This is where a React context and/or Redux is helpful.